# Full external USB drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, debian, raspberry-pi

I've got a Linux system (Raspbian running on a Raspberry PI). An external USB 1 TB drive (formatted in FAT32) is attached and mounted to the system.

Here it is my problem:

- When I launch the `df` command, I've got `0` Bytes available on the mounted drive
- I remove some files (through `rm -rf some_gb_sized_directory/`) and run the `df` command again
- The situation is not changed and I still have `0` Bytes available
- I reboot the system and the situation is not changed
- Tried to run `fsck.fat -v /dev/sda1`:
  `fsck.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)`
  `Logical sector size is zero.`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What's its filesystem?

Comment: It's a FAT32 file system.

Comment: Tried `fsck.fat`? Make sure you run it with the filesystem unmounted.

Comment: Tried `fsck`, but it didn't help...

Comment: Still, maybe it will help if you attach the output of `fsck.fat -v`

Comment: Here it is (question edited).

Comment: Seems you need some rescuing: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1908329